# What parametric equations could be used to replicate these surface plots seen on 3d printed vases?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions, 3d-printing

I came across this interesting link and am curious to know what generic equations were used to create these waves on the vase surface? It was mentioned that special dates could be incorporated into the equations, for example ones birthday. Here is an example Vase and the source link.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

[image]

[Sine Wave Generator](https://www.3dforprint.com/3dmodel/sine-wave-vase-generator/2116)